# How does an L bracket on a Canon 70D limit the LCD display movement?

Tags: accessories, canon-70d

I am considering buying an L bracket for my Canon 70D. The camera has a vari-angle (foldable and twistable) LCD display, and the mounting of the L bracket will limit the degrees of freedom of the screen movement. For example, the product description on [Really Right Stuff's homepage](http://www.reallyrightstuff.com/s.nl/it.A/id.2306/.f) includes the following:

> Note About LCD Articulation: Remember that any L-plate, including ours, will limit articulation of the LCD screen on this camera. An L-plate, by design, has a dovetail that is adjacent to the left-hand side of the camera. The very presence of this dovetail will prevent the user from twisting the LCD screen when it is open.

I am not sure though how to fully interpret this. Does this mean the display cannot be opened when stowed with the backside out once you mount the L bracket (since this requires twisting)? Or is it a less "severe" limitation? The images available on RRS's and other manufacturers' homepages don't really tell the whole story in my opinion.

Comment: I have feeling most folks who use an L-plate will also shoot tethered from a tripod if they wish to see a screen rather than the viewfinder.

Comment: @MichaelClark I don't really follow you. I will shoot mostly from a tripod, but use liveview for manual focus.

Comment: When tethered, the screen being viewed is not the one on the camera, it is part of the PC/MAC/tablet/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's less severe: look at the images on the page you linked to.  The side view that shows the bracket shows how the bracket impinges over some of the screen hinge, so while you do have some movement you won't have full movement. The two images that show the LCD screen extended probably are showing you the limits of movement, before the screen bumps into the bracket. So, for example, you could swing the LCD out 90 degrees, then twist it, and push it back to almost-but-not-quite 180 degrees if you want to before the back of the LCD bumps up against the bracket.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right and looking at the pictures again I agree with you. I just wanted to be 100% sure before buying this overpriced little gadget. But maybe 99.99% is good enough! :)

Comment: I found [this review](http://www.amazon.com/Kirk-Release-L-Bracket-Canons-PZ-157/dp/B00H6XJNS4#cm_cr_dpwidget) that confirms your answer.

Comment: Since I now have bought a Kirk L bracket for Canon 70D + battery grip, I can personally confirm that it works the way it's described in this answer. I'll therefore accept it.